# On the Dominated Convergence Theorem

Tags: lebesgue-integral

I'm trying to show:

If $f \in L^1([0,1])$, then 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_0^1n \ln\left(1+\frac{|f(x)|^2}{n^2} \right)dx=0
$$

*Solution:* I want to apply de Dominated Convergence Theorem. However, I don't find a suitable  $h \in L^{1}([0,1])$ such that 
$$
\left| n \ln\left(1+\frac{|f(x)|^2}{n^2} \right)  \right|=\left|\ln\left( \frac{n^2+|f(x)|^2}{n^2}\right)^n  \right| \leq h(x) \quad \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}.
$$
Any hint will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: $\ln(1+x) \le \sqrt{x}$ holds for each $x \ge 0$, so you're immediately done.